# Drawing Petri Network using Networkx module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, petri-net

As the question says, is there any way to draw a Petri Net to a cmd using networkx module in python?

If not what are the options availible to make do this task? I am working on a project for uni to make a Petri Network and to print it after the user chooses one of the transitions enabled. The source code is done with the various objects and it does what is meant to do.

Comment: This may be doable, but I am not sure what a Petri Net is, and I'm not sure what you mean by draw one to a cmd.

Comment: A Petri Net, is a bypartite graph with transitions between the nodes, a sort of directed graph. With drawing to a cmd I mean, printing to a command line window the graph with the appropriate graphics

Comment: could you provide an example of what kind of drawing you would like to get?

Answer (score 0):

Ok old post and an partial answer: I do not know about Python/networkx concerning drawing bipartite graph but my [Petri editor](https://github.com/Lecrapouille/TimedPetriNetEditor) can generate LaTeX and Graphviz figures with colors on transitions. If this can help you.